# RHEL Linux: Discover what processes are using a specific disk

Tags: linux, redhat, lsof

I need to discover what processes are using a specific disk.  This is a multipath disk but I cannot find a way of setting up a way to record to a log file what processes are running when a particular disk is being read or written to.  I know the major:minor block IDs using lsblk then lsof but these only show current activity and as there currently is none, I cannot find out the process that uses this disk.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: you can try to use `fuser -v `  to get it or `lsof | grep ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lsof`. Lsof revision lists on its standard output file information about files opened by processes. for example this command below will list all files that are opened for writing:

```
lsof | grep -e "[[:digit:]]\+w > mylogfile.log"
```

you can redirect the command to log file if you which with the redirect operator `>`